# File redirection before command

Tags: bash, redirect, wc

I tested two commands that produce the same output:

```
$ wc -l < input_file
6
$ < input_file wc -l
6
```

The first command redirects input_file to stdin which is then read by `wc`. I don't understand the second command and would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: They're equivalent. Redirection can be anywhere on the line.

Comment: you can even write `wc < input_file -l`

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223882/posix-placement-of-stdin-redirection-in-cmd-vs-cmd-in